# Api Auto Discovery error in mule logs

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

Api Auto discovery Error 400... when i deploy my api in cloud(anypoint through runtime manager) it got deployed. but, when i tried to get a response from postman, it says "service not available",i am not able to get a response back from postman.

Answer (score 0):

Is it error 503? In that case the explanation is that the API is not correctly paired to the API in API Manager with client credentials and Autodiscovery. See https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/API-returns-503-Service-Unavailable-error-to-clients